# Question about Reish Lakish

Tags: talmud-gemara, amoroim

Why is Reish Lakish sometimes called in the Gemara "Reish Lakish" and sometimes "Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish"? Why not just use one title?

Comment: Is your question specifically about Reish Lakish / R Shimon b Lakish, and you want to know what each of the names mean? Or are you asking about why anyone would have more than one name, in which case why limit it to this one case?

Comment: @JoelK I have an assumption that there's a reason that in certain places one name is used and in others, the other, but I don't know whether that's true, and if it is, what's the reasoning?

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=604

Comment: @JoelK thank you

Comment: Update: I see that it seems that Lakish was a city that he was likely from. So the question remains though: Why sometimes referred to as the "head" of the city and sometimes "the son/product of" the city?

Comment: @Gre''i in the link Joel K brought, most commentators (haven't read all of them yet) agree that this is probably a mistake in various manuscripts of the Gemara - it was probably written ר"ש בן לקיש and that somehow evolved into ריש לקיש.

Comment: Rabbi Reuvein Margolios in his work לחקר שמות וכינויים בתלמוד, page 6 https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33639&st=&pgnum=5&hilite=